# I want to load a text file into a data grid and apply a regular expression

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

```
string[] s = File.ReadAllLines(ofdl.FileName);
List<code> codes = new List<code>();
string textfile = ofdl.FileName;
var textvalues = s;
foreach (var item in textvalues)
{
   codes.Add(new code() { Value = RemoveEmptyLines(item) });
}
dataGrid.ItemsSource = codes;
under_label.Content = textfile;
under_label1.Content = codes.Count();
```

```
private string RemoveEmptyLines(string lines)
{
    return lines = Regex.Replace(lines, @"\n\s.+", "");
}
```

I want to load a text file into a data grid and apply a regular expression

but this code don't work for me

Comment: Which portion is not working?

Comment: regex does not apply.

Comment: I don't know how to apply the regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need Regex to search for empty strings. [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace) method will do.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(ofdl.FileName);
var codes = lines.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToList();

dataGrid.ItemsSource = codes;
under_label.Content = ofdl.FileName;
under_label1.Content = codes.Count;
```

Comment: It is not an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

[datagrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7flo.jpg)

I want to exclude the part of the circle separately

```
   List<code> codes = new List<code>();
                    string[] s = File.ReadAllLines(ofdl.FileName);

                    string textfile = ofdl.FileName;
                       var textvalues = s;

                       foreach (var item in textvalues)
                       {
                       codes.Add(new code() { Value = item});
                       }
                    dataGrid.ItemsSource = codes;



                }
            }
        }

        private void streams()
        {


        }

        private string RemoveEmptyLines(string lines)
        {
            return lines = Regex.Replace(lines, @"\n\s.+", "");
        }
```